# cacert curl equivalent in scala/java HttpsClient

Tags: scala, https, cacerts

I am able to make the following curl command:

```
curl --cacert ${CACERT} --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -X GET ${APISERVER}/api
```

now I am trying to do the same with scala code, I saw many examples of SSL connection, but I am just presenting CA cert to use the specified certificate file to verify the peer.

I tried something like this:

```
    object HttpsServerContext {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("cacert.crt");
       
    
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(is);
    
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
        .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(null);
    ks.setCertificateEntry("caCert", caCert);
    
    tmf.init(ks);
    
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    }



//    this is the way I used the httpsConnections 


  val nvl4RcGet = HttpRequest(uri = uri)
  .withMethod(HttpMethods.GET)
  .withHeaders(RawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + tokenfileContents))

val res = Http().singleRequest(nvl4RcGet, getSslContextForNoCertificateCheck)
```

but it still does not works, and failed with error:

```
[ERROR] [06/07/2022 12:50:16.572] [EVENTSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] [akka://EVENTSystem/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-17/TLS-for-flow-1-1] host and port supplied for connection based on server connection context
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: akka://EVENTSystem/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-17/TLS-for-flow-1-1: exception during creation
```

any suggestion?